# Visual Studio 2019 Debug assertion failed

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program experimenting with malloc linked lists. [I keep getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H45ns.png). It says:

**Debug Assertion Failed!**

**Program: ...ource\repos\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe**

**File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp**

**line: 904**

**Expression: _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(block)**

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <corecrt_malloc.h>
#include <cstddef>

struct node_t {

    int value;
    struct node_t* next;
};

void printList(node_t* headNode) {

    node_t* currentNode;
    currentNode = headNode;

    while ((currentNode->next) != NULL) {
        printf("%d, ", currentNode->value);
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }

    printf("%d", currentNode->value);
    currentNode = currentNode->next;
}

void addNode(node_t* headNode, int nodeValue) {

    node_t* currentNode = headNode;
    node_t* tempNode = headNode;

    while ((currentNode->next) != NULL) {
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
        tempNode = currentNode;
    }

    currentNode = (node_t*)(malloc(sizeof(node_t)));
    currentNode->value = nodeValue;
    tempNode->next = currentNode;
    currentNode->next = NULL;

}

void popHead(node_t* headNode) {

    node_t* newHead = headNode->next;
    free(headNode);
    headNode = newHead;

}

void freeAllNodes(node_t* headNode) {

    node_t* currentHead;
    node_t* tempNode;
    currentHead = headNode->next;
    free(headNode);

    while ((currentHead->next) != NULL) {
        tempNode = currentHead;
        currentHead = tempNode->next;
        free(tempNode);
    }
    free(currentHead);
}

int main()
{
    node_t* nextNode;
    node_t* tempNode;
    node_t* headNode;

    headNode = (node_t*)(malloc(sizeof(node_t)));
    headNode->value = 1;
    headNode->next = NULL;

    printList(headNode);
    printf("\n");

    addNode(headNode, 2);

    printList(headNode);
    printf("\n");

    addNode(headNode, 3);

    printList(headNode);
    printf("\n");

    popHead(headNode);

    freeAllNodes(headNode);
    return 0;
}
```

I believe the problem is in Pop Head

note: The reason i am not using 'new' and 'delete' is because i want to keep it as close to regular c as possible.

Comment: Press retry and check the call stack.

Comment: `headNode = (node_t*)(malloc(sizeof(node_t)));` just why ?

Comment: Switch the `Stack Frame` (on the toolbar) back to your code to see what was being executed when this happened.

Comment: The code you've presented is essentially C, not C++.  If you're going to compile it as C++ you should use it - constructors, `new`, `delete`, `std::cout`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `headNode = newHead` assignment in `popHead` is assigning to the local `headNode` variable.  This change is not passed back to the caller.  The result is that when you call `freeAllNodes` you will try to free this head node a second time.

Possible solutions include passing head node as a reference (`void popHead(node_t *&headNode))` or returning the new head node pointer (`node_t *popHead(node_t *headNode) { ... return headNode; }`.